# How to change Tabsheet background?

Tags: vaadin, vaadin7

I have a tabsheet with the background of black but when I create a tabsheet as

```
TabSheet tabsheet = new TabSheet();                             
tabsheet.setStyleName(ValoTheme.TABSHEET_TABSHEET_FRAMED);
```

Everything is white including the tab.  I want it to have the background color of black.

Right now I use the below style and it does have the background black but it does not have the tab style so that's why I want to use the above style but then it does not have the background black.

```
tabsheet.setStyleName(ValoTheme.TABSHEET_CENTERED_TABS);
```

How do I make a tabsheet have the black color please? I use latest vaaadin 7 version and valo theme.

Thanks

Comment: Can you attach any screenshots? Also the code above won't compile. There is no constant named TABSHEET_TABSHEET_FRAMED in ValoTheme class.

Comment: Use addStyleName method to add your custom style name. Then simply add style in css to make the tabsheet background black.